# how store an array into sqlite using node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite, csv

everyone! 
There is csv file, I parsed it (using fast-csv) and now it is stored as an array. Now i want to replace this array into SQLite DB using node.js. Can someone tell me how can i do it?
Here is my code:

```
 class Person {
     getData(filename) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let arrayData = [];
                const csv = require('fast-csv');
                csv.fromPath(`${filename}.csv`, {
                    headers: true,
                    strictColumnHandling: true,
                    delimiter: ',',
                    ignoreEmpty: true
                })
                    .on('data', data => arrayData.push(data))
                    .on('end', () => {
                        resolve({
                            arrayData,
                            title: filename,
                            columnCountData: Object.keys(arrayData[0]).length,
                            rowCountData: arrayData.length + 1, // data plus header
                        });
                    })
                    .on('error', (error) => {
                      reject(error);
                    });

            });
        }
    }
    let person = new Person();
    person.getData('person')
          .then((array) => {
              const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    // open the database
              let db = new sqlite3.Database('./ook.db',sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE, (err) => {
                  if (err) {
                      console.error(err.message);
                  }
                  console.log("DB is connected");
              });
              db.close((err) => {
                  if (err) {
                      console.error(err.message);
                  }
                  console.log('Close the database connection.');
              });
              console.log(array);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
              console.log('все накрылось, потому что: ', error)
          });
```

Comment: You can import CSV data using the sqlite3 shell, no other language required: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import

Comment: Or just iterate over your array and insert an elements worth of data at a time, of course. (I'm assuming each element should be one row)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have a native array type, but it does support Unicode text and blobs:
https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

So you need to convert your array into one of these formats, and store that in the database. Or, more conveniently, just read in the whole file, and store **that** in the db, **before** parsing it. But be aware that this might (or might not, depending one the data) be wasteful of storage space, if that's a concern some kind of custom binary serialization of your array might be preferred.

Note: the [default max length of strings and blobs](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) is 1 billion, and you can't set that limit higher than 2^31-1, but this should not be a problem in practice, you should not store objects that big in a database.